# \n new line character won't work

Tags: javascript

I tried making a web page by writing

```
document.write("This is the first line \n And this is the second");
```

The desired effect is:

```
This is the first line
And this is the second
```

But I get this:

```
This is the first line And this is the second
```

I tried writing `<br>` inside and it worked. But Why writing an escape `\n` didn't? Anything I am doing wrong? I am using Firefox.

Comment: Good question... many might be wondering the same thing...

Comment: You might like to experiment to see what happens if you put newline characters directly in your html. Try also multiple spaces in a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. Its just the `\n` character is valid in text related elements like, alert() and `<textarea>`.

The `document.write()` command writes to the body of the site or the display (in the HTML). Substitute `<br>` in place of the `\n` here since you are writing HTML in the page

Comment: That sums it up..For HTML, we need <br>

Answer (score 4):

instead of `\n` you have to use `<br/>`, so that the browser understands it

```
document.write("This is the first line <br/> And this is the second");
```

Comment: The browser does "understand" newline characters, but they have a different meaning in html.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `<pre>` tags for things like `\n`, and `<br/>` for ordinary HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/FxpcA/

```
document.write("<pre>This is the first line \n And this is the second</pre>");
```